# In wordpress add page attribute to custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I have created custom post type for my project and I want to add custom post type with page attribute. I have done this with following code:

```html
function register_pt_boutique()
{
    register_post_type('boutique', array(
        'label'           => 'Boutiques',
        'description'     => 'This post type represents the featured items on the homepage.',
        'public'          => true,
        'show_ui'         => true,
        'show_in_menu'    => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap'    => true,
        'hierarchical'    => true,
        // 'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'featured', 'hierarchical' => true, 'with_front' => false),
        'query_var'       => true,
        'has_archive'     => true,
        'menu_position'   => '7',
        'supports'        => array('title', 'page-attributes','thumbnail'),
        // 'taxonomies' => array('page-attributes'),
        'labels'          => array(
            'name'               => 'Boutiques',
            'singular_name'      => 'Boutique',
            'menu_name'          => 'Boutiques',
            'add_new'            => 'Add Boutique',
            'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Boutique',
            'edit'               => 'Edit',
            'edit_item'          => 'Edit Boutique',
            'new_item'           => 'New Boutique',
            'view'               => 'View Boutique',
            'view_item'          => 'View Boutique',
            'search_items'       => 'Search Boutique',
            'not_found'          => 'No Boutique',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Boutique Found in Trash',
            'parent'             => 'Parent Boutique',
        )
    ));
}
```

Using this code page attribute option come with two fields ("parent" and "order") at admin side but without "template" field option. I want page attribute with "template" field.

Comment: You dont need to specify the templates in the register_post_type function. Instead, just create your post-templates like you would do with your normal page-templates. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/254772/how-to-add-page-attribute-template-to-custom-post

Answer (score 1):

Just as you gave the template name in the page template file:

```
Template Name: <template name>
```

You can specify the custom post types as ***Template Post Type*** where you want to show:

```
Template Post Type: <custom_post_type_1>, <custom_post_type_2>, <custom_post_type_3>
```

for example:
I want to add page attribute to the *portfolio* one of my custom post type:

In my page template, I have added:

```
Template Name: Portfolio Design
Template Post Type: portfolio
```

Also, don't forget to add 'page-attributes' to 'supports' array during cpt registration:

```
'supports' => array(
            'custom-fields',
            'page-attributes'
        ),
```

If you want to change label 'Page Attributes' then assign to 'attributes' in 'labels' array i.e :

```
'labels' => array(
    'name' => 'Portfolios',
    'singular_name' => 'Portfolio',
    'attributes' => 'Page Attributes'
),
```

A screenshot of the dashboard for custom post type editor is:
[image: page attribute for custom post type = portfolio]

Answer (score -2):

from wordpress 4.7 you can include the field "template" directly from de file https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/03/post-type-templates-in-4-7/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)